# Understanding a C++ Macro that uses #

Tags: c++, macros

I have a C++ macro with a syntax that I have never seen before:

```
#define ASSERT(a) \
if (! (a)) \
{ \
  std::string c; \
  c += " test(" #a ")";
}
```

Couold you please explain me the use of # in here?
I wanted to put the macro in a static function but before I would like to fully understand what it does.

Thanks

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

Comment: I'm almost *positive* there's a duplicate of this question, but the built-in search feature doesn't seem to be cooperating...

Comment: Didn't you forget a backslash?

Answer (score 7):

The use of `#` in a macro means that the macro argument will be wrapped in quotes `""`:

```
#define FOOBAR(x) #x

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << FOOBAR(hello world what's up?) << std::endl;
}
```

output

```
hello world what's up?
```

---

#### Another example

In the below we display the contents of foo.cpp, and then what the file will look like after the pre-processor has run:

```
:/tmp% cat foo.cpp
#define STR(X) #X

STR (hello world);
```

...

```
:/tmp% g++ -E foo.cpp # only run the preprocessor
# 1 "foo.cpp"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "foo.cpp"


"hello world";
```

---

#### Where can I read more?

Check out the following link to a entry in the `cpp` (C Pre Processor) documentation:

- [**Stringification - The C Preprocessor**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

Answer (score 2):

Within a macro the `#` "stringifies" the variable name. By "stringify" I mean, the variable name is transformed into a string literal.

For example when you have the following macro:

#define PRINT_VARIABLE_NAME(var) printf(#var);

And use it like that:

```
int i;
PRINT_VARIABLE_NAME(i);
```

It would print "i".

In your case the string would get concatenated with "test".

Comment: What on earth does *stringifies* mean? I'm sure you know what it means, and so do I, but please do take the time to explain it to the uninitiated.

Comment: and how can I have the same result in a method?

Comment: @dau_sama this is a feature of the preprocessor only, so it only works with macros. You can't do the same in a regular function.

Comment: At runtime, this is not possible, since variables are then mere memory locations. If you want this functionality you have to use the preprocessor with its macros.

Answer (score 0):

`#a` is a string containing the literal `a`. See [Stringfication](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) for more.